# Handle event setting notification on brower?

Tags: firebase, browser, notifications, config, settings

I have an issue that I want to catch event when notification on browser is opened or closed?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e27h2.png)

Do you have any solution or any library can handle setting notification on browser? I am using firebase. That's amazing if I handle notification by this library. Thank you so much!